# How to add Reverse Polarity Protection on 2-cell battery charger IC?

Tags: charger, reverse-polarity, bms

I'm using the [MP2672A](https://www.monolithicpower.com/en/mp2672a.html) ([datasheet](https://www.monolithicpower.com/en/documentview/productdocument/index/version/2/document_type/Datasheet/lang/en/sku/MP2672AGD/document_id/9059/)) 2-cell balanced charger IC for charging 2 li-on batteries. Normal PFET reverse polarity protection (RPP) doesn't work here as the IC has a balance function which connects to the middle point of the 2-cell series setup.

How can I add reverse polarity protection on 2-cell battery charger IC?

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Current schematic of the charger circuit.

[image: current schematic]

Comment: Can you avoid the need for polarity protection? Use a connector which cannot be connected incorrectly?

Comment: I wish. To be honest, this isn't the biggest concern, but if there was a low hanging fruit way of doing this, I'd like to as these are 21700 single cells that could be inserted manually versus within it's case.

Comment: That's exactly the reason why products do not have user changeable cells (unless there is only one), but battery packs that can't be connected incorrectly. Or built-in batteries where user can't change them.

Comment: That's a great point. I'll focus more on that then.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using an NPN transitor to ultimately achieve what I was wanting -

1. be able to provide reverse polarity protection, and
2. be able to charge the batteries with the onboard charger IC.

[image: Schematic]